# Validate expired oidc token with jose4j

Tags: openid-connect, jose4j

On our endpoint, we get an OIDC token and a refresh token. When the OIDC token has expired, we want to refresh the token using the provided refresh token.
Currently, except for disabling all default validators, I see no way to only exclude expiry validation.

Is it possible in Jose4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only exclude expiry validation? Or only include expiry validation?

Setting up the JWT Consumer like this will basically only do expiry validation.

```
JwtConsumer consumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
   .setDisableRequireSignature()
   .setSkipSignatureVerification()
   .setSkipDefaultAudienceValidation()
   .setRequireExpirationTime()
   .build();
```

To effectively exclude expiry validation you could use something like `.setAllowedClockSkewInSeconds(2000000000)` on a `JwtConsumerBuilder`

Comment: Thanks :), was talking about excluding expiry validation.